# Animate TD width change

Tags: html, css, animation

I have a table

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Cell 1 | Cell 2 |
| Cell 3 | Cell 4 |

I'm setting the width for the first column = 0, the width of the table is 100%.
So, the size of the 1st column is the same as we have for the content here.

I'm dynamically adding a content for the first column

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Cell 1 Cell 1 Cell 1 Cell 1 | Cell 2 |
| Cell 3 | Cell 4 |

So, the first column gets bigger and bigger but the CSS property for the WIDTH is the same because it's static = 0.

I need to animate width change for the 1st column.

Do you have any idea?

`* {transition: 1s all}`

it doesn't work

Here is an example.
When you click on the first button, there is no animation
When you click on the second, everything works fine because we are manually changing the width.

```js
function addContent() {
  var content = document.getElementById("content");
  content.innerHTML += "content";
}

function changeWidth() {
  var content = document.getElementById("content");
  content.style.width = "70%";
}
```

```css
* {
  transition: 1s all;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table tr td:first-child {
  width: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

table,
td {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

input.add-content {
  margin-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="content">Column 1-1</td>
    <td>Column 1-2</td>
    <td>Column 1-3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Column 2-1</td>
    <td>Column 2-2</td>
    <td>Column 2-3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Column 3-1</td>
    <td>Column 3-2</td>
    <td>Column 3-3</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<input type="button" value="Add a content to the first column" class="add-content" onCLick="addContent()" />

<input type="button" value="Set column width to 70%" class="add-content" onCLick="changeWidth()" />
```

[Codepen is here](https://codepen.io/Mark-twen/pen/ExGZJwR?editors=1111)

Comment: Can you provide the code for what you've tried so far?  No one can do anything with these tables in MarkDown format. Please made a code snippet.

Comment: Yes, link has been added to the question. Thanks.

Comment: Please see [ask]. Links to code don't cut the mustard here. Replace your mockups with demos containing actual markup using the editor. Also take the [tour] so you know how to use this site.

Comment: everything is done. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. I don't think a `<td>` can be animated directly, but you can put an element inside of that which can be animated.

Here I have an outer `<span>` which I've added a red border to just so it can be seen. This element will animate.  When something animates it must have a defined value to animate from.  Since the default width is `auto` you can't smoothly transition from `auto` to a value. So as soon as the page loads it needs to determine what that value is by measuring it.  Then when asked to re-measure and set the width, it can animate as desired.

Note that I have to use an inner element to measure to get the actual content width, otherwise if we measured the outer element it would just give the width as what was previously set.

Also note that this may not be exactly what you want since you can't really set this as a percentage of the table width, but instead this will animate to the size of the content, or a percentage of the column width, not the table width.

```js
var contentWrapper = document.getElementById("content-wrapper");
var contentInner = document.getElementById("content-inner");
setWidth();

function addContent() {
  contentInner.innerHTML += "content";
}

function setWidth(desiredWidth) {
  if(desiredWidth){
    contentWrapper.style.width = desiredWidth;
  } else {
    var contentRect = contentInner.getBoundingClientRect();
    contentWrapper.style.width = contentRect.width + 'px';
  }
}
```

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table tr td:first-child{
  width: 0;
}

#content-wrapper {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid red;
  transition: all 1s;
}

table,
td {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

input.add-content {
  margin-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span id="content-wrapper">
        <span id="content-inner">Column 1-1</span>
      </span>
    </td>
    <td>Column 1-2</td>
    <td>Column 1-3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Column 2-1</td>
    <td>Column 2-2</td>
    <td>Column 2-3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Column 3-1</td>
    <td>Column 3-2</td>
    <td>Column 3-3</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<input type="button" value="Add a content to the first column" class="add-content" onCLick="addContent()" />

<input type="button" value="Set content width to 70%" class="add-content" onCLick="setWidth('70%')" />

<input type="button" value="Set content width to match content" class="add-content" onCLick="setWidth()" />
```